# loop to add combinations of variables into factor analysis

Tags: r

I am trying to take a list of variable combinations which looks like this:

```
"Combined_t2|t1_lag8" "mean_RT_200_all"
"Combined_t2|t1_lag8" "mean_RT_1000_all"
"Combined_t2|t1_lag8" "PRP"
...
"Combined_abwidth" "dual_average_accuracy"
"Combined_abwidth" "mean_RT_dual"
...
"PRP" "Dual_cost"
"PRP" "dual_average_accuracy"
...
```

and pass these pairs of variables through a process which will run an EFA (factor analysis) on each pair. The code I have so far is:

```
for(i in 1:length(Cog_vars_list)){
  Cog_data_test<-
    Data_final%>%
      select(i)
  
  data_stand <-data.frame(scale(Cog_data_test, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE))
  
  EFAResult = fa(data_stand, fm="pa", rotate = "oblimin")
  
  
  EFAResult$loadings
}
```

the 'cog_data_test' selects the columns with the two variable names from the larger data frame, and then runs the EFA on that. The tricky part is selecting one pair of variables at a time from the list.
Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: They are variable names. They represent columns of data which are numeric.Cog_data_test is a data frame containing two columns of numeric data - determined by the two variable names in the list.

Comment: dput(head(Cog_data_test))
structure(list(mean_RT_1000_all = c(1474.734521, 878.2980769, 
1754.824519, 1878.624765, 1033.50235, 955.1539337), dual_average_accuracy = c(0.958333333333333, 
0.872340425531915, 0.8, 0.82051282051282, 0.911111111111111, 
0.911111111111111)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: list(`1` = c("Combined_t2|t1_lag8", "mean_RT_200_all"), `2` = c("Combined_abmag_t2_lag8_minus_lag3", 
"mean_RT_200_all"), `3` = c("Combined_abmag_t2_1.0_minus_lag3", 
"mean_RT_200_all"), `4` = c("Combined_abwidth", "mean_RT_200_all"
), `5` = c("Combined_abdepth", "mean_RT_200_all"), `6` = c("Combined_lag3vslag8_residuals", 
"mean_RT_200_all"))
>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using `lapply` :

```
result <- lapply(Cog_vars_list, function(x) {
          Cog_data_test<- Data_final[x]
          data_stand <-data.frame(scale(Cog_data_test, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE))
          EFAResult = psych::fa(data_stand, fm="pa", rotate = "oblimin")
          EFAResult$loadings
})
```

Comment: Hi. That doesnt seem to work. It throws up errors relating to the EFA ("Error in fac(r = r, nfactors = nfactors, n.obs = n.obs, rotate = rotate,  : object 'eigens' not found"). yet when I paste in a pair of variable names into select like this : (select("mean_RT_1000_all","dual_average_accuracy") the EFA works fine?

Comment: I don't know how `fa` function works and what it returns. The answer was to demonstrate how you can select columns from `Cog_vars_list` and pass it to `fa` function.

Comment: @JayG Can you provide `dput(Data_final)` as well so that I can test the answer myself. Don't add it in the comments, edit your post to include data.

Comment: Sorry, I cant put the full data here (too big and breaches ethics requirements for my study). Could it be because the list of variable names is stored as separate strings (e.g. "PRP" "Dual_cost") while the 'select' function requires two columns separated by a comma? (e.g. select("PRP", "Dual cost")) ? Perhaps by not separating them the fa function is treating it as only one column (and trying to factor itself?)...

Comment: @JayG you do not have a list but a dataframe which needs to be handled differently.